# Triac based switching with reverse voltage protection

Tags: arduino, relay, esp8266, solid-state-relay, triac

I have created an ESP8266 based controlling circuit which seems to be working fine. But there is only one problem when rotating the fan speed regulator I always see some lights flicker. I think I need to put some reverse voltage protection. And how I can do that I am not sure.

Here is how my schematics looks like.

[image]

Is there any suggestions why this is happening and how can I protect my switches to flicker from that?

Comment: I'd experiment with an RC-snubber across the TRIAC that switches any inductive (or capacitive) load. However I don't have a good rule of thumb for sizing the components, hence a comment rather than an answer. You'll have to know the approximate current drawn by the fan to be able to size the components.

Comment: 2A is usual current drawn by AC fan with 220V and 50Hz frequency.

Comment: How did you manage voltage phase? Is it some null comparator you did not show? Current spikes may happen than fan turned on on peak voltage. Since you control phase by MCU, you can create "soft start"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to check is make sure the HLK-SM05 is providing the correct 5V output that is constant, I also don't see any bypass power capacitors on the schematic which could also be causing brownouts on the board. The voltage to the MOC3021 should also be constant.

If those are constant then start looking at the snubber.

With inductive loads the triac doesn't shut off because the voltage cycle and current cycle are not in sync. So it may be necessary to adjust the snubber for the load by having an RC snubber with an adjustable resistor as show and described in this article:

[image]
Source: [ST AN308: CONTROL BY A TRIAC FOR AN INDUCTIVE LOAD HOW TO SELECT A SUITABLE CIRCUIT](https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/AN308.pdf)

You could also change the resistor until it lines up, usually triacs need an RC snubber.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and replying. Your suggestions are really helpful. Can you please suggest what size of Power Bypass Capacitor i should be choosing for this 5v 5w power supply?

Comment: It depends on the max switching current draw of the NodeMCU (also you need a really good trace like 30-50mil between the power supply and the NodeMCU. Look and see if there is anything, but I'd probably start with a 10uF in parallel with an 0.1uf. Its a good idea to use planes instead of traces for Vcc because the paraisitc resistance of traces can be a problem and lead to voltage drop.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would love to mark your answer with tick. Just trying to understand your suggestions a bit better.

Comment: Yes i keep my traces usually 40mil (1mm). 

According to datasheet i can see 220uF capacitor is required for typical application https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_HI-LINK-HLK-5M05_C209907.pdf .